# Adding JPA support to an existing Maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I've been working on a project in IntelliJ for a while now using Maven (My god, maven is cool!). For the persistence I wanted to use JPA.

The issue is that I'm not sure how I can enable JPA support for my existing project, following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-jpa-support.html) didn't work since my code still can't use tags such as `@Entity`.

It looks like IntelliJ is adding a new package (?) for JPA that my existing code can't access. Here's my package structure:

[image: Package structure]

My existing code is in the src directory, while IntelliJ created the JPA directory for JPA.

Is there something I can do to add JPA to the existing code, or should I move my existing code to the JPA directory? I would like to keep using Maven.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> while IntelliJ created the JPA directory for JPA.
>   it's weird. IDEA sholdn't create new source module if you just try to add JPA support to existing code.

Try to add JPA facet to your existing module via Project Settings

Answer (score 2):

[image: Adding JPA support]

File--> Project Structure --> Facets --> click on + --> Select JPA